# Big problem with memory between methods

Tags: objective-c, memory

i don't understand this problem:

i've 2 class A and B, in A view i've two Button, ButtonCreate and ButtonAccess.

In B there is this method:

```
-(NSDictionary *) returnData
{
   NSDIctionary *data= [NSDictionary withObjectsAndKeys.....];
   return data;
}
```

In A i've also a property `@property(nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *dictio`, and in .m file `@synthesize dictio = _dictio`.

ButtonCreate IBAction -->

```
B *secondaryClass = [[B alloc] init];
_dictio = [[secondaryClass returnData] retain];
[B release];
```

ButtonAccess IBAction -->

```
NSString *value = [_dati ObjectForKey... ];
```

Problem: if i push more than once ButtonCreate, in Instruments i see a memory leak, but if i cut off the "retain" in ButtonCreate method, i've a crash when i access data from ButtonAccess.

I really don't understand how can i do...can you help me?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't release the old value of `_dictio`, and you didn't release `secondaryClass`

```
B *secondaryClass = [[B alloc] init];

if (_dictio != nil) 
     [_dictio release];

_dictio = [[secondaryClass returnData] retain];
[secondaryClass release];
```

But, since you declared your property as retain, you can just take advantage of the property doing this for you.

```
B *secondaryClass = [[B alloc] init];
self.dictio = [secondaryClass returnData]; // sends retain to new, release to old
[secondaryClass release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in A, i think it could solve your problem:

```
ButtonCreate IBAction --> B *secondaryClass = [[B alloc] init];
self.dictio = [secondaryClass returnData];
[B release];
```

Comment: thanks, in this way it sounds good and it works, thanks also to other people who answer

Answer (score 0):

It appear you are trying to release B, rather than the instance of B which you named secondaryClass.

```
B *secondaryClass = [[B alloc] init];
_dictio = [[secondaryClass returnData] retain];
[B release];
```

Should it not instead be:

```
...
[secondaryClass release];
```